# Replacing large-dimensional ODE systems with one PDE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems

Is it possible to replace a large-dimensional system of differential equations with one partial differential equation?

Comment: The answer obviously depends on the details of a specific case. Would you care to elaborate on yours? Note that the reverse operation is a routine aspect of numerical analysis of PDEs. However the resulting ODEs have special "sparse" structure.

Comment: Clearly the heat equation is an example, in that the motion of the molecules of a heated material is described by a huge system of ODEs, but in a certain limit the material behaves like a continuum. But this sort of ``rescaling'' is really the domain of expertise of physicists. Maybe ask on http://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Same answer for vibrating string. That was how it was actually presented in a physics class I took. 

Comment: "Hamilton-Jacobi" may be a useful keyword.  Many Hamiltonian systems can be described in terms of either individual particle trajectories (ODE) or propagation of the corresponding wavefront (PDE).

Comment: In what sense replace?

Comment: Self-promotion: http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6235

Answer (score 2):

Let me single out a situation which goes the other way around: how a system of ODE is describing the propagation of singularities for a principal type PDE.

Take a linear (pseudo)differential operator of real principal type with smooth coefficients: the principal symbol $p(x,\xi)$ is real-valued and $dp\wedge \xi\cdot dx\not=0$ (verified for the wave equation or  a non-vanishing real vector field). Then the singularities are moving along the bicharacteristic curves, which are the integral curves of the Hamiltonian vector field of $p$,
$$
H_p=\frac{\partial p}{\partial \xi}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x}-
\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial \xi}.\quad 
$$
Solving the system of ODE, $\dot \Gamma=H_p(\Gamma)$ is enough to understand the propagation of singularities: if $p(x,D) u\in C^\infty$ the the wave-front-set of $u$ is invariant by the flow of the Hamiltonian vector field. There is no need to solve the PDE if you are only interested in singularities.

Answer (score 2):

This idea is studied in the field "kinetic PDE." See these lecture notes by Clément Mouhot:

http://cmouhot.wordpress.com/1900/10/25/mathematical-topics-in-kinetic-theory-part-iii-course/

Ch 2 in particular should be of interest.